# Boostrap Padding Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add padding to my Bootstrap website. However, when i resize the browser, the navigation bar messes up completely instead of staying fixed. Here is a link for pictures https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LQGe.jpg

html code:

```
<nav class="nav`bar navbar-custom">
<div class="container2">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">WHO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WHAT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WHERE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
    `body{
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
}
.navbar-custom {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:#000;
    border-radius:0;
    padding-top: 50px;

}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#000;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    color: #000;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open >a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color:#eeeeee;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
    background-color:#33aa33;
}


.container {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    font-size: 20em;

  }

  .footer-right{
      padding-top: 70px;

      font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;

    }`
```

Comment: Because your navbar is static, padding will also affect the navbar. Can't tell because there is no CSS in this question. Try to reset the padding from `.navbar-custom` by setting `padding: 0;` or `padding: 0 !important`

Comment: What's the point of the padding? Instead of applying that to body, you should probably apply it to your outer container instead. And you don't want 400px of padding on mobile... that's wider than most phones' viewport width. So you can remove the padding with a media query wherever it seems most appropriate based on your layout https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/QgLKJQ

Comment: hi i dont want my text to be right at the end of the web page, i want it to be around 200px in

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems with your code formatting but got the idea. What you need the most ist the class `navbar-fixed-top` added to your navbar so it'll be always on top. And I also suggest to make custom classes instead overriding the `container` class completely. Better would be `container custom-container` - so it'll still got it's basic functionality and additionally your changes. I also see that you're using the class `container2` which isn't defined and therefore can't work as a container.

[Working Example](https://www.bootply.com/ffSZYUWoFS)

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">WHO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WHAT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WHERE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container custom-container">

  <div class="text-center">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS

```
body{
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
}

.navbar-custom {
    background-color:transparent;
    color:#000;
    border-radius:0;
    padding-top: 50px;

}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#000;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    color: #000;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .open >a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color:#eeeeee;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
    background-color:#33aa33;
}


.container-custom {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    font-size: 2em;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<body>` is directly under the `<head>` though. So, it would mess up your container. Michael Cooker is pointing you in a good direction.